# Delete (remove) column in google sheet over gspread Python like sheet.delete_row

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

Is there a method like worksheet.delete_row in gspread google-sheet?
I tried:

```
delete = sheet.range('A1:A1000')
        for cell in delete:
            cell.value = ""
            sheet.update_cells(delete)
```

but that only delete all values, not column.
Can anybode help me?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your question, I cannot understand about `a method like worksheet.delete_row`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: In Gspread is a lot of possibilities. I can call sheet.delete_row(1). But I’m looking a solution for removing a column.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I could understand that you want to delete the columns. But I cannot understand about the relationship between your script and your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Answer:

*There is no method in `gspread` to delete an entire column, like `Workbook.delete_row`, however you can do this with a batch update.*

#### Code sample:

```py
spreadsheetId = "your-spreadsheet-id"
sheetId = "id-of-sheet-to-delete-column-from"

sh = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)

request = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "deleteDimension": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": sheetId,
                    "dimension": "COLUMNS",
                    "startIndex": 0,
                    "endIndex": 1
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
result = sh.batch_update(request)
```

This sample will delete column A, but make sure to change the `startIndex` and `endIndex` to be of the column range you wish to delete.

**Edit:**
If you do not know the `sheetId` of a given sheet, you can get it using the following:

```py
sheetName = "theSheetName"
sheetId = sh.worksheet(sheetName)._properties["sheetId"]
```

Note that this is not needed for the original sheet of a Spreadsheet, as this will ***always*** be `0`.

#### References:

- [Method: `spreadsheets.batchUpdate` | Sheets API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [API References - gspread 3.4.0 documentation - `batch_update(body)`](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.batch_update)

---

#### Update 2020-04-15:

This script was merged with `gspread` master today from [pull request #759](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/pull/759) as method `delete_column()`.

> The method will be available in the next release `v3.5.0`.

A method for `delete_columns()` was also added as a parallel method to the existing `delete_rows()` from [pull request #761](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/pull/761).

Comment: Very good answer. Would you be interested in contributing the code to gspread? (as `delete_column()` method)

Comment: Of course! Would be happy to help. Shall I create a pull req on github or make a suggestion issue first?

Comment: Great! No need for a suggestion for this one. Please go ahead and create a pull request.

Comment: Anybody knows how to use that on - Sheet1? without sheetId?

Comment: Sheet1 ID is always `0`.

Comment: I added the information to get a specific sheet ID to my answer, though it still stands that the first (ie **original**) sheet of a spreadsheet will always have an ID of `0`.