# Delete rows in google sheets using only javascript CHROME EXTENSION

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have created chrome extension, from popup i added my input values in google sheets using javascript Fetch 'put' method in "background.js", now i want to delete this value from google sheet, so delete row in google sheet using only javascript. for example i used javascript array pop() method to delete last value, but it does not delete row in  google sheet. but when i get values in console.log, it seems that pop() method works, but does not do anything in google sheets. Can someone help me please?
here is my code,  javascript fetch 'put' method background.js

```
  let init = {
    method: 'PUT',
    async: true,
    body:JSON.stringify(params),
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
      'contentType': 'json',
       };
   fetch(
    `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${SPREADSHEET_ID}/values/${SPREADSHEET_TAB_NAME}!A:C?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED`,
      init)
      .then((response) => console.log(response))

        }
      })
    }
```

and get method where i use javascript array pop() background.js:

```
  let request = {
          method: 'GET',
          async: true,
          headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          'contentType': 'json',
          };
        fetch(
            `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${SPREADSHEET_ID}/values/${SPREADSHEET_TAB_NAME}!A:C`,
            request)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then(function(data) {
            let vals = data.values;
            vals.pop()
              console.log(vals)
              
            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You're only removing the last row from the local variable - at no point are you sending this request to Sheets.*

#### More Information:

As per the documention on [Row and Column Operations](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn), you can delete rows or columns by making a [batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) request.

#### Making the Request:

To delete the last row, you first need to find the length of the data array obtained from the `spreadsheets.values` request:

```js
let vals = data.values;
let noOfRows = vals.length
```

Then with this, you can send a `spreadsheets.batchUpdate` request with a `deleteDimension` request in the request body:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "deleteDimension": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": 0, // modify this to be your sheet gid
          "dimension": "ROWS",
          "startIndex": noOfRows - 1,
          "endIndex": noOfRows
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Things to remember:**

- You need to specify the sheetId of the Sheet to remove the last row from. This is the `gid` value in the URL when viewing a specific sheet, and ***not*** the same as the Spreadsheet ID.
- `deleteDimension.range.startIndex` and `deleteDimension.range.endIndex` are 0 indexed, so you will need to specify the `row number - 1` of the rows you wish to delete.

#### References:

- [Row and Column Operations | Sheets API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn)

  - [Delete rows or columns](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn#delete_rows_or_columns)
- [Method: `spreadsheets.batchUpdate` | Sheets API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)

#### Related Questions:

- [Delete (remove) column in google sheet over gspread Python like sheet.delete_row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61223341/11551468)

Comment: thanks so much, can u show me request code example please?